# how can I select a random element from an array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

How can I make the program select a random element from an array. So:

```
A=[1 2 3 4]
```

random= random element of A

I tried randsample(A,1) and randi(A) and neither worked so what can I do

Comment: A(randi(numel(A)))

Comment: Also, `randsample(A,1)` works for me. You need the Statistics Toolbox though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `randi`  to generate a random index over the length of `A`. No fancy toolboxes needed:

```
>> A = [1 2 3 4];
>> x = A(randi(length(A),1))

x =

     4

>> x = A(randi(length(A),1))

x =

     3
```

etc.

`randi(A)` does not work because the first argument of `randi` is the bound of the random integer. Always check the docs:

```
>> help randi
 randi Pseudorandom integers from a uniform discrete distribution.
    R = randi(IMAX,N) returns an N-by-N matrix containing pseudorandom
    integer values drawn from the discrete uniform distribution on 1:IMAX.
```